# How to clone "class tree" with other classes name in JAVA?

Tags: java, java-8, clone

Suppose I have a 2 inherited classes with a really lot of fields ,

I want to create another "inheritance family" with classes C,D that would have the same values - content (in RUN TIME) as in example below..

```
package server.api.analytics;

public class A {

    protected String param1;
    protected String param2;
    protected String param3;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public String getParam3() {
        return param3;
    }

    public void setParam3(String param3) {
        this.param3 = param3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setParam1("out_param1");
        b.setParam2("out_param2");
        b.setParam3("out_param3");
        b.setParam4("out_param4");
        b.setParam5("out_param5");
        System.out.println(b.toString());

    // OUTPUT:
     B{param1='out_param1', param2='out_param2', param3='out_param3', 
         param4='out_param4', param5='out_param5'}
  //  EXPECTED : 
     D{param1='out_param1', param2='out_param2', param3='out_param3', 
         param4='out_param4', param5='out_param5'}
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected String param4;
    protected String param5;

    public String getParam4() {
        return param4;
    }

    public void setParam4(String param4) {
        this.param4 = param4;
    }

    public String getParam5() {
        return param5;
    }

    public void setParam5(String param5) {
        this.param5 = param5;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
                "param1='" + param1 + '\'' +
                ", param2='" + param2 + '\'' +
                ", param3='" + param3 + '\'' +
                ", param4='" + param4 + '\'' +
                ", param5='" + param5 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

B{param1='out_param1', param2='out_param2', param3='out_param3', param4='out_param4', param5='out_param5'}
```

I don't want to make like "copy contractor" and go over all properties cause there are a lot , and if I do "deep copy" with clone the class name will be the same

Example expected:

```
D{param1='out_param1', param2='out_param2', param3='out_param3', param4='out_param4', param5='out_param5'}
```

Comment: It's hard to get what the question really is here... Can you show where you're doing the **cloning**? And about your `CLONED_NEW_NAME` output, is this just a question of what content your `toString` produces? Otherwise, are you trying to generate alternative types/classes when objects are cloned?

Comment: Use a copy constructor. If your class has so many fields that this seems onerous, then the class is probably too big anyway.

Comment: What will be different about C and D as compared to A and B, aside from the class names?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson , Just updated question , I want to make "copy paste" to inheritance tree , like copy content but to other objects names...

Comment: @Boris the Spider , it is a lot of mess to do with "copy contractor" need to go over about 100 properties..is it any easier way ?

Comment: A `class` should not have 100 properties! Absolutely not.

Comment: Maybe it would help us helping you if you explained the reason why you want or need to do this, I have a hard time visualising a use-case for what you're asking.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson  , Yep I'm trying to make data migration using google datastore - objectify , I want to write the "same" data into 2 different entities with same content , the name of the entity is the table name ...so i want to clone the class tree with inheritance into different entities tree and store into DB. like( a-->b   to:   c-->d)

Comment: @ Boris the Spider  , i don't really have 100 , it is just to emphasise that i don't want to go over all properties , cause i have a lot of nested classes inside that does't mentioned in the question. Just want to understand if there is any option to clone the tree to other classes...

Comment: @VitalyT, I think I understand then. Wouldn't it be easier to have only one class structure, a-->b, and then two different export classes/methods to store a-->b into different entities?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson  , Give me an example please how can I "export" a-->b into different entities ? P.S: "a->b" is production structure I can't change it i need only create other entities names to store into DB , with "old" content

Comment: Create an `Exporter` class that you can configure by setting the entity name to export to in constructor and then have an export method, `export(B b)` that will store the given object in the entity set for this particular instance of the `Exporter`. This example is of course grossly simplified since I know nothing about the API and what needs to be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BeanUtils.copyProperties((Object dest, Object orig)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) of the [apache common library](https://commons.apache.org/):

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for
>   all cases where the property names are the same.

For example:

- B extends A
- D entends C

Below code can copy all fileds from `B` to `D`:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        B source = new B();
        source.setParam("param");
        source.setParameter("parameter");
        D target = new D();
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(target, source);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(source.getParam());  // param
        System.out.println(source.getParameter());  // parameter
        System.out.println(target.getParam()); // param
        System.out.println(target.getParameter()); // parameter
    }

    public static class A {
        String param;

        public String getParam() {
            return param;
        }

        public void setParam(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        String parameter;

        public String getParameter() {
            return parameter;
        }

        public void setParameter(String parameter) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
    }

    public static class C {
        String param;

        public String getParam() {
            return param;
        }

        public void setParam(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }

    }

    public static class D extends C {
        String parameter;

        public String getParameter() {
            return parameter;
        }

        public void setParameter(String parameter) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, will it change the class name to other ? E.g : "D"

Comment: @VitalyT No, see my update. You need to create an empty `d` before copy.

Comment: Will check it , do you have the maven properties for Pom.xml ?

Comment: @VitalyT <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>

Comment: BWT, If I need inheritance I need create , E.g "class D extends F"  ??

Comment: @VitalyT No, it will check all fields in `D` and `B`, if both exists, it will copy. You can take a try.

Comment: ok ..the result is : d = {D@695} 
 param1 = "out_param1"
 param2 = "out_param2"
 param3 = "out_param3" ...it means that it didn't copy the "root" NO  ....   
        b.setParam4("out_param4");
        b.setParam5("out_param5");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170452/discussion-between-vitalyt-and-neng-liu).

Comment: @VitalyT Seems this library can not regonized fields end with numbers. See my update code, it works fine.